# asp.net code displays code itself instead of output in browser

Tags: asp.net, razor

The following code displays as it is in browser instead of expected output. I have the table in sql server 2008. I have this code in webmatrix.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
@{
var db = Database.Open("databasename"); 'database name in sql server is 'databasename'
var selectQueryString = "SELECT column_date, sum(qty1) as quantity1, 
sum(qty2) as quantity2, sum(qty3) as quantity3
from tbldaily group by column_date order by column_date"; 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>First table test</h1> 
<table> 
<tr>
<th>at_date</th> 
<th>quantity1</th> 
<th>quantity2</th> 
<th>quantity3</th> 
</tr>
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{
<tr> 
<td>@row.column_date</td> 
<td>@row.quantity1</td> 
<td>@row.quantity2</td> 
<td>@row.quantity3</td> 
</tr> 
}
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I feel there is mistake somewhere in this code. Can you help me to fix this? Please let me know if you want more information regarding my database structure or table that may help to understand my scenario better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing [Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29) with WebPages. Name your file *.cshtml and remove the first line which is for WebPages. The rest of your code is valid C# razor.

Comment: i removed first line and line <!doctypehtml> and saved as .cshtml. Before it was .aspx but still it displays everything before <html> tag as text in web page...and even line @for each as text...

Comment: It was a problem with applicationhost.config file. It was corrupted in my computer. I installed same version webmatrix in another computer and replaced applicationhost.config file from the other computer into mine. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think he needs the opposite of that. Keep it .aspx.
So wherever you have @ tags to mark the asp code, use aspx escapes instead

```
<% For i As Integer = 0 To .... %>
   <tr> <td> <%= row.column_date %> </td> ......
<% Next%>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about aspx codes.... now I'm  gettting error for the same razor codes (as stands in my question) - `Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'database does not exist in the current context`....